# How do you limit Dojo parsing to just a subsection of the page?

Tags: dojo

I've read in several places that this is possible, but cannot figure out how to do it.  I have all my Dijits in the same place, but they're showing up for an instant on page load, presumably because Dojo has to parse the entire page to find them, which takes some time.

How can I tell Dojo that they're all inside the same container, so only bother parsing that one thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `parseOnLoad`, that will parse the entire document.

If you are calling `dojo/parser`'s `parse` function directly, you can pass it a DOM node or ID and it will only parse declarative widgets under that node.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html#parse

Either way, you are still likely to get a flash of unparsed content, so you might want to set up a loading overlay, then hide it only after the parser runs.  An alternative approach is to create a single top-level widget for your application, make it extend `_TemplatedMixin` and `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`, and put your declarative content into its template.